# 2010 FG Falcon dash lights and starter motor wont work

Tags: electrical, ford, ignition, no-crank-no-start

Dash lights don't work or fuel gauge or anything on dash plus car will not turn over but you can hear some clicking under bonnet but not from starter motor

Comment: Are any of the electrical circuits working?  e.g. Wipers, lights, heater blower?

Comment: What is the battery voltage when the headlights are turned on?

Comment: Hi handy howie yea the lights horn I pretty sure the wipers work and the heater fan comes on when ignition is turn on but can not turn the fan off at all now or change fan speed not sure about voltage when lights are turned on as don't have a anything to check that sorry mate appreciate your help tho

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.